# Bug comes out in func2 when func1 and func2 is most likely the same Python

Tags: python-3.6

I'm making a GUI program. Code is like below:

```
def func1(arg):
  ...
  pyautogui.locateOnScreen(eval('path.'+arg))

def func2(arg):
  ...
  pyautogui.locateOnScreen(eval('path.'+arg))

def arg():
  type = str(entry1.get())  
  return type

def func(arg):
  func1(arg())                  #x
  for k in range(1, 3):
    func2(arg())                #y
    func1(arg())
func(arg)
```

I get an error

```
'eval('path.'+type) typeError:must be str type, not func' when **func** run to #y code.
```

I don't know what is going wrong because the #x code run just fine and the `func1` and `func2` are most likely the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: today i tested again and no error. sometime my script just return error and sometime not. And even Sometime even skip some line of code.